# How can I change the display a message depending on which number the user has selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I want when somebody input a number **lower than 4.2**, my app shows `message` **as result**, but i can't make it happen.

I already tried with `return`.

**JS code**

```
let resultEl = document.getElementById("results")
let numberEl = document.getElementById("number__select")
let message = "mAs: 0.5 y kV: 1.0"

function calculate() {
    if (numberEl <= 4.2) {
        resultEl.textContent = message;
    } else {
        resultEl.textContent = "error"
    }
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleRx.css"/>
    <script src="Rxappjs.js"></script>
    <title>HVDN Rx app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Valoraciones de Rx</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="box">
            <form action="">
                <div class="values">
                    <label for="peso" id="peso__label">Peso</label>
                    <input class="text__input" type="number" step="0.1" id="number__select" placeholder="Peso" 
                    min="0" required>
                </div>
           
                <button id="calcular" onclick="calculate()">Calcular</button>
            </form>
            <p id="results"></p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable numberEl set to an html element and therefor it will never be less than or equal too 4.2. Try to get the value of that element instead:

```
let resultEl = document.getElementById("results")
let numberEl = document.getElementById("number__select")
let message = "mAs: 0.5 y kV: 1.0"

function calculate() {
    if (numberEl.value <= 4.2) {
        resultEl.textContent = message;
    } else {
        resultEl.textContent = "error"
    }
}
```